# m.example.com vs. responsive website

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, mobile, responsive-webdesign

I am working on SEO project for the website aasaanjobs.com. The website has two different entity for desktop users and mobile users. I was thinking deindexing `https://m.aasaanjobs.com/` completely and focusing on desktop version of the website which is `https://www.aasaanjobs.com`.

If I am keeping both the website live, I feel Google will find duplicate content which will impact directly on the search engine ranking.

So to avoid that confusion I have decided to deindex the mobile version. In this scenario, users can still browse the mobile website but Google can't index it.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here or provide me any other solution to fix this duplicate content issue.

Answer (score 2):

> If I am keeping both the website live, I feel google will find duplicate content which will impact directly on the search engine ranking.

Google knows the difference and will not see it as duplicate content. If you do that there will be a difference in ranking and it will be for the worse.

> So to avoid that confusion I have decided to deindex the mobile version. In this scenario, users can still browse the mobile website but Google can't index it.

80% of first page results are mobile friendly sites.
And by deindex, do you mean actually use a noIndex, noFollow? Google does not like that and a quick search will confirm that.

> Provide me any other solution to fix this duplicate content issue.

**You mentioned the answer your questions title.**

**Go responsive.** That takes care of mobile to desktop compatibility, having to maintain 2 sites, paying 2 sub/domain names and decreases the chances of conflicting content from mobile to desktop.

Comment: Agreed, the responsive is the ultimate solution, but converting the current website in the responsive format will take time. I was thinking to rank the desktop website for both the searches desktop and mobile. By doing this it will save time and efforts on seo. Mobile searches will get the www.domain.com but when a user clicks to the site, they will be redirected to the mobile site.

Comment: Is it going to be different content and will you continue to update both, or looking for a way to get rid of the Mobile pages on the old site and the new one will be responsive and both new mobile and desktop users will be targeted to stay on the responsive one?

Comment: If I keep the domain m.domain.com then I have to add unique content to avoid duplicate content penalty. What I am asking is, if I keep the desktop website index . Will google rank the website in the mobile searches? Because users will be automatically redirected to m.domain.com (De-index) version of the site.